# Why a "set" whose elements is contingent on the truth value of a proposition is a set?

Tags: set-theory, constructive-mathematics

> Let $P$ be a proposition (such as Goldbach's conjecture) that we can state precisely, but that we do not necessarily know to be true or false. Now define $$ S =
> \begin{cases}
> \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\},  & \text{for $P$ is true} \\
> \{\{\varnothing\}\}, & \text{for $P$ is false }  \\
>  \end{cases}$$

This is a "set" constucted to prove that "The Axiom of Regularity implies the Law of the Excluded Middle, if interpreted in the language of constructivism" on page 138 of *Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations*, Eric Schechter.

I don't know how to show that $S$ is a set from $\bf{ZFC}$.

Since page 138 is "visible" on googlebooks([here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eqUv3Bcd56EC&pg=PA138&dq=The+Axiom+of+Regularity+implies+the+Law+of+the+Excluded+Middle,+if+interpreted+in+the+language+of+constructivism&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=uEBMUfy_NcqskgX8ooH4BQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=The%20Axiom%20of%20Regularity%20implies%20the%20Law%20of%20the%20Excluded%20Middle%2C%20if%20interpreted%20in%20the%20language%20of%20constructivism&f=false)), I assume it is OK to post a screenshot here.

[image]

Comment: This seems quite weird to me.  My own (limited) understanding is that in strict [constructivist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(mathematics)) terms, such a set $S$ may not exist!  In order for it to exist one would first have to either constructively prove $P$, or to constructively refute $P$.  The author seems to be applying LEM to show that Regularity implies LEM.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: To me it looks like they're trying to blame Regularity for something that's really the fault of the Subset axiom. If $P$ isn't already known to be either true or false, then how can we defend using $P$ to select elements of a subset? A properly constructive subset axiom ought to be something like: _If_ $\forall x\in A: \phi(x,y,z,\ldots)\lor \neg\phi(x,y,z,\ldots)$, _then_ $\{x\in A\mid \phi(x,y,z,\ldots)\}$ is a set. And with this formulation, $S$ couldn't be shown constructively to exist.

Comment: (It looks like I'm substantially agreeing with @Arthur)

Comment: No, I disagree. The separation axiom is supposed to be taken literally here. You can always form $\{ x \in X : \phi(x) \}$, whether or not you know what $\phi (x)$ is. This is true in the internal logic of a topos, which is a model for intuitionistic set theory.

Comment: @Arthur I don't know much about constructivism, but couldn't one avoid LEM by defining $S = \{x : x = \{\emptyset\}\text{ or } x = \emptyset \mathbin{\And} P\}$?  Perhaps this is what the author meant.

Comment: @Trevor: Your definition still requires one to know the truth/falsity of $P$ to determine whether $\emptyset$ belongs to $S$.  As such, I believe a constructivist would not accept it as defining a set unless $P$ itself was first constructively proved/refuted.  Part of this might just be that constructive set-theory would not be accepted by constructivists.  (I'm really not well-versed enough in either area to say that this is the case, but this is an impression that I have.)

Comment: @Arthur I don't know what constructivists accept, but I was thinking of IZF, which has the usual axiom schema of separation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory#Intuitionistic_Zermelo.E2.80.93Fraenkel

Comment: @ArthurFischer One could hold such views, but again, that is not what is under discussion. It is certainly the case that one cannot determine whether or not $\emptyset \in S$ without determining $P$, but that does not disqualify $S$ from being a set. There is a perfectly good, well-defined semantics for intuitionistic logic that does not make reference to provability or other such meta-level things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, $S$ exists due to the Axiom of Separation (sometimes called the Axiom of Subsets, or of Comprehension).

Hopefully you agree that $A=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ is a set.

Now $S$ is simply the set $\{x\in A \mid x=\{\varnothing\} \lor P \}$.

Then it is easy to prove that $P$ implies $S=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ and that $\neg P$ implies $S=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$.

It is important to note that $S$ *does not itself know* that we have defined it in such a strange manner. A set knows only what its elements are, and "$S$" is actually just an alternative name for either the set $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ or the set $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$. We don't know which, but our ignorance is really about which set the letter $S$ stands for, not which members a particular known set has. (However, this distinction is seldom observed when speaking about sets casually -- or even semi-formally).

---

How this could possibly be used to argue that "the Axiom of Regularity implies the Law of the Excluded Middle, if interpreted in the language of constructivism" I cannot fathom.

First off, it is more or less implicit in saying "ZFC" that the axioms are to be interpreted in the framework of classical first-order logic -- and there the law of the excluded middle is *automatically* true, independently of which axiom system we use to reason about it.

Second (and at last as puzzling), the defintion of $S$ here has nothing at all to do with the Axiom of Regularity; it would work exactly the same in ZF$-$Reg or even in an explicitly ill-founded set theory such as ZF$-$Reg$+$AFA.

Comment: @Henning The language ZFC is formulated in can be directly interpreted in intuitionistic first-order logic. Apparently there is a strongly classical character in the notion of well-foundedness; certainly it is the case that well-founded induction relies on classical logic.

Comment: @ZhenLin: I agree that the _language_ can be interpreted in intuitionistic logic; but the axioms themselves are usually presented in a context where one doesn't really distinguish carefully between different formalizations of an axiom as long as they are _classically_ equivalent. So when one just says "ZFC" without referencing particular symbolic formulas for the axioms, we don't have enough information to speak meaningfully about its intuitionistic consequences.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Arthur's objection that the definition of the set $S$ seems to presume the Law of Excluded Middle, rendering the argument tautological.  However, I think this can be fixed by instead defining

$$S = \left\{x \in \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} : x = \{\emptyset\} \text{ or } (P \mathbin{\And} x = \emptyset)\right\}.$$

The existence of this set is guaranteed by the Separation axioms.
Note that the set $S$ is not only non-empty but is *inhabited*, because we know $\{\emptyset\} \in S$. The form of the Axiom of Regularity assumed in the quoted text then allows us to specify $x \in S$ such that $x \cap S = \emptyset$.
We know that $x = \emptyset$ or $x = \{\emptyset\}$.  If we can decide which one is true (which the quoted text seems to suggest that we can do) then we can decide the statement $P$: if $x = \emptyset$ then $\emptyset \in S$ and so $P$ is true, and if $x = \{\emptyset\}$ then $\emptyset \notin S$ and so $P$ is false.  This would prove LEM, because $P$ was an arbitrary statement.

According to the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory#Intuitionistic_Zermelo.E2.80.93Fraenkel), in Intuitionistic Zermelo–Fraenkel
set theory the Axiom of Regularity is replaced by the axiom schema of set induction (perhaps to avoid this argument for LEM.)

EDIT: Thinking more about it, it seems like the set $S$ defined by cases in the quoted text can still be proved to exist intuitionistically, provided that we interpret the definition as $$S = \left\{x \in \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} : (P \mathbin{\And} x \in \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}) \text{ or } (\neg P \mathbin{\And} x \in \{\{\emptyset\}\})\right\}.$$
However, the problem with this definition is that although it makes $S$ non-empty, we cannot show that $S$ it is inhabited unless we already know that $P$ is decidable.  Presumably the form of the Regularity Axiom used in the text only applies to inhabited sets, although the author seems to ignore the distinction between "inhabited" and "non-empty".